# Trying to retrieve tags set on my Amazon EC2 instance at runtime

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS Workspace EC2 instance that has a few tags set on it. I can clearly see the tag names and their values in the AWS Workspaces console. I would like to retrieve the tags and their values at runtime on the instance in .NET. I found this article, but it is 7 years old and very out of date. https://gist.github.com/gortok/6908999db5fe293eec5c

Can anybody help me find a modern code example for doing this? Can anyone point me at the correct NuGet package that includes what is needed? I already include the package references below for various other AWS services.

```
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.CloudFront" Version="3.7.3.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.Core" Version="3.7.12.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.EC2" Version="3.7.75.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.1.19" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement" Version="3.7.5.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="AWSSDK.SQS" Version="3.7.0.48" />
```

Comment: So you are saying that you want code that is _running on the Workspace_ to retrieve its _own_ tags? Please note that a Workspace is _not_ the same as an Amazon EC2 instance. The hard part would be for code running on the Workspace to know _which_ Workspace it is running on. While Amazon EC2 instances have [Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html), I'm not sure whether that is available on a Workspace. If the code can discover _which_ Workspace it is running on, then getting the tags is easy.

Comment: If Instance Metadata is not available, one method might be to identify the Workspace's **private IP address** and then use `DescribeWorkspaces()` and iterate through the results, looking for a Workspace that matches the IP address. Then, retrieve the Tags associated with that Workspace.

Answer (score 1):

To describe your tags on an EC2 instance in .NET, you can use the [AmazonEC2Client.DescribeTags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EC2/MEC2DescribeTagsDescribeTagsRequest.html) method that is part of the **AWS SDK for .NET v3** (the code example you referenced is an older version of the .NET EC2 SDK).

Code is:

```
var client = new AmazonEC2Client();
var response = client.DescribeTags(new DescribeTagsRequest 
{
    Filters = new List<Filter> {
        new Filter {
            Name = "resource-id",
            Values = new List<string> {
                "i-1234567890abcdef8"
            }
        }
    }
});

List<TagDescription> tags = response.Tags;
```

If you are not familiar with this SDK, please reference the ***AWS SDK for .NET Developer Guide***.

[What is the AWS SDK for .NET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

Information about the packages for this service can be found here:

[Working with Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/ec2-apis-intro.html)